# display variable name instead of value in foreach loop

Tags: android, google-maps, foreach

Hiii am using maps in my app. i have to add multiple marker in my map. i have placed all the markers in ArrayList . and now using foreach loop am placing markers. Till here every thing is working fine. but i want to place title to that marker. and that title should be variable name which i added in array list.
This is my arraylist

```
 placeslist  = ArrayList<LatLng>()
            pietrasanta = getLocationFromAddress(this, "pietrasanta the italian resturant")
            Ikea_alexandra = getLocationFromAddress(this, "Ikea alexandra resturant,317")
            candlenut_resturant = getLocationFromAddress(this, "candlenut resturant,17A ")

            placeslist.add(pietrasanta )
            placeslist.add(Ikea_alexandra)
            placeslist.add(candlenut_resturant)
```

getting lnglat from this getLocationFromAddress method

```
 fun getLocationFromAddress(context: Context, strAddress: String): LatLng {
        val coder: Geocoder = Geocoder(context)
        val address1: List<Address>
        lateinit var p1: LatLng



        try {
            address1 = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5)
            if (address1 == null) {

            }
            val location: Address = address1.get(0)
            location.latitude
            location.latitude
            p1 = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return p1
    }
```

And now with the help of foreach loop am adding markers in onMapReady()

```
  placeslist.forEach(){
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(it).title())    
        }
```

till here everything is fine . the problem is raising when am tring to add .title()
in the place of title i want to display variables lable in arraylist instead of values that is  pietrasanta, Ikea_alexandra, candlenut_resturant with their respective markers . can anyone please help me how to add variable names as string instead of its value.

i tried with this    `mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(it).title(it.toString()))`
but instead of name latitude and longitude values are displaying as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ArrayList, use HashMap :

```
var placeslist : HashMap<String, LatLng> = HashMap<String, LatLng> ()

placeslist.put("pietrasanta", getLocationFromAddress(this, "pietrasanta the italian 
resturant"))
placeslist.put("Ikea_alexandra", getLocationFromAddress(this, "Ikea alexandra 
resturant,317"))
placeslist.put("candlenut_resturant", getLocationFromAddress(this, "candlenut 
resturant,17A "))
```

and for retrieving the data :

```
for(key in placeslist.keys){
        // here key will be your identifier (as you want variable name)
        // placeslist[key] will be you LatLng object for particular key
}
```

but, do not add duplicate key name in same hashmap.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add position value in add marker .for(key in placeslist){
            mMap.addMarker( MarkerOptions().position(placeslist.values).title(key))
        }..Did this way but position() is showing error.

Comment: Done this way  mMap.addMarker( MarkerOptions().position(placeslist.getValue(key)).title(key))   Thank you so much .